# Measurable function equal zero

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a positive RV and $g(X)$ a measurable function. If for a fixed $u^*\ge 0$ we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{u^*<X\le u}]=-\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{u<X}],\ \forall u>u^*,$$
and:
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{u<X\le u^*}]=\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{u<X}],\ \forall u^*>u\ge 0.$$
Does the above imply $\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{u^*<X\le u}]=\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{u<X\le u^*}]=0$ which then implies $g(X)=0$?

Any hints are appreciated.